# Pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence: understand this using limit definition

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I have a question on the difference between uniform and pointwise convergence in probability. We know that pointwise convergence in probability does not imply uniform convergence in probability. In more details, let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a sample of real valued i.i.d. random variables. Let 
$$
f_n(X_1,...,X_n;\beta): \mathbb{R}^n \times B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
be a function of $X_1,...,X_n$ and of a parameter $\beta\in B$. Let 
$$
f(\beta): B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
be a function of a parameter $\beta\in B$.

Pointwise convergence states that
$$
f_n(X_1,...,X_n;\beta)\rightarrow_P f(\beta) \text{ }\forall \beta\in B
$$ 
i.e. 
$$
\forall \beta\in B, \forall  \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0 \text{ } \exists \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon,\beta}\in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } \forall n> \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon,\beta}\text{ } P(|f_n(X_1,...,X_n;\beta)-f(\beta)|>\epsilon)<\delta
$$
Uniform convergence states that
$$
\sup_{\beta\in B}|f_n(X_1,...,X_n;\beta)-f(\beta)|\rightarrow_P 0 
$$ 
i.e. 
$$
\forall  \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0 \text{ } \exists \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon}\in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } \forall n> \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon}, \forall \beta\in B\text{ } P(|f_n(X_1,...,X_n;\beta)-f(\beta)|>\epsilon)<\delta
$$

---

**Question**

What is wrong in the following argument: suppose pointwise convergence holds. Take $\sup_{\beta\in B} \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon,\beta}$ and show that uniform convergence is implied by setting $ \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon}:=\sup_{\beta\in B} \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon,\beta}$.

Comment: If you have a pointwise but no uniform convergent sequence you will get $\bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon}:=\sup_{\beta\in B} \bar{n}_{\delta, \epsilon,\beta} = \infty$ so no $\bar{n}$ independent of $\beta$ can be found

Comment: Thanks. Why? Can't there be all finite?

Comment: Ok, I see. I may have a sequence of natural numbers that is not bounded. Thank you

Comment: OFC they CAN be finite, but then the convergence is uniform… but if you have an unbounded sequence it's not…